# Raising Custom Exceptions (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to raise a custom exception in my code whenever negative values are entered but I keep getting errors. My code is:

```
class LessThanZeroError(Exception):
    pass

def get_BMI():
    try:
        height = int(input('Enter height in inches:'))
        weight = int(input('Enter weight in pounds:'))

        if height or weight < 0:
           raise LessThanZeroError('height and weight must be positive values')
        BMI = (weight * 703 // height**2)
        return BMI

    except ValueError:
        print('Error, height and weight must be numbers')
print(get_BMI())
```

Here is the output screenshot.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj3bk.png)

I tried raising an exception to occur whenever height or weight have a value from the user that is less than or equal to zero, but I get an error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: height is truthy when positive. For any positive number of height, the if block will be executed.

Also for the future, post text of the error message rather than an image unless there there is just no way to show the error without a screenshot.

Comment: @Amolgorithm it doesn't save memory nor is it redundant, in fact, it improves the self-documenting aspect of the code

Comment: i agree with @Amolgorithm.  i almost never `return` statements. And also the variable `BMI` would be cleared when the function completed.

Answer (score 3):

The `height` and `weight < 0` are two separate statements in the `if...or...:` conditional statement. If `height == 0`, it will return `True`, so the indented code afterwards will be passed.
Therefore, you would change the condition of raising the exception to

```
if height < 0 or weight < 0:
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is raised because your condition of raising the exception is `if height or weight < 0`. With integers, variables are `True` as long as they are not equal to 0. So the `height` part of your `if` statement will be `True` as long as it is not 0, which is why your special error is raised.

Plus, you might want to change your line of code to
`if height <= 0 or weight <= 0`,
because it wouldn't make sense for someone to have no height or weight.
But if you just want it to not accept negative numbers, then your code would be:

```
if height < 0 or weight < 0:
```